# Assigning variables to values in a text file with 3 columns, line by line

Tags: bash, variables, awk, text-files

I've got a .txt file with three columns, each separated by a tab, and 264 rows called PowerCoords.txt.  Each row contains an x (column 1), y (column2) and z (column3) coordinate.  I want to go through this file, line by line, assign each value to X,Y, and Z, and then input those variables into another function.

I'm new to bash, and I don't understand how to specify that I want the value in Row 1, Column 2 to be the variable Y, and so on...

I know this is likely super simple and I could do it in a flash in Matlab, but I'm trying to keep everything in bash.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that what you describe is the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. If you tell us more about what you're doing with the 3 values we can suggest the right approach.

Comment: Hi Ed - The 3 values are xyz coordinates for a single voxel location in the brain.  Each row is the location of a voxel.  This is my input file. I have an existing function that takes 3 inputs (xyz) and creates a 6mm sphere around the coordinates that I input.  I want to take each value from each of the three columns, input that to my function of interest, then move to the next row (line) and input those three values, and so on...  I hope this helps. Thanks for your input!

Comment: For example, the first row is: 57  14  30 (no header, each value separated by a tab).  I want to label each of these numbers as a variable X, Y, and Z, and then input those into another function using $X $Y $Z.  Then I want to move to the next row and do the same, and on and on.

Comment: When you say you have a function - a shell function or something else? Do they need to be separate variables X, Y. and Z or would an array a with 3 entries a[1], a[2], a[3] work?

Comment: An array would work just as well, so long as I could call a single element at a time, as you suggest.

Comment: The function is: fslmaths ~/data/standard/MNI152_T1_2mm -mul 0 -add 1 -roi 50 1 50 1 50 1 0 1 point -odt float ....  Where the values 50 50 50 would be replaced by each x, y, and z coordinate, respectively.

Comment: So it's a shell function named "fslmaths"? You may as well use @WilliamPursells answer then after setting IFS='\t', adding the `-r` flag to `read` (i.e. while IFS='\t' read -r x y z rest`), and quoting the variables. Do NOT use what was posted by bashophil as it has a ton of errors that will cause cryptic failures wen you least expect it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read x y z; do
  echo x=$x y=$y z=$z
done < input.txt
```

The above requires that none of your columns contain any whitespace.

EDIT:

In response to comments, here is one technique to handle numbering the lines:

```
nl -ba < input.txt | while read line x y z rest; do
  ~/data/standard/MNI152_T1_2mm -mul 0 \
    -add 1 -roi $x 1 $y 1 $z 1 0 1 point -odt float > NewFile$line
done
```

Comment: William - I tried this solution, but I haven't been able to make it work.  What do the x y z values stand for in the "while read x y z" loop?  I don't have labeled columns, just 3 columns full of numbers.

Comment: The x, y, and z are the names you are giving the columns.  This will read the input and assign the first column to a variable named `x`, the second to `y`, and the remainder of the line to `z`.  What is happening when you try this?

Comment: while read x y z; do
> echo x=$x y=$y z=$z
> done < MNI_Coords_Power2011_XYZ.txt
31 61 634 z=30 <--- The numbers 31 61 are correct. They are the X and Y coordinates of the last row in the txt file. The problem is the third coordinate...The actual value should be 63, but it's reporting 634

Comment: I should add that during this process, I'd also like to keep track of which line I'm on for each assignment of the X,Y,Z variables, so that I can label the resulting file as NewFile23 when I'm on line 23.  If that's possible.

Comment: It sounds like you have more data on the line than just the three columns.  A typical technique for handling that is `while read x y z foo` so that the extra data is not assigned to `z`.  But it really sounds like `bash` is the wrong tool for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

William Pursell's answer is much smarter, but in my straight-forward beginners mind I tried following some time ago:

```
#!/bin/bash

data="data.dat"
datalength=`wc $data | awk '{print $1;}'`

for (( i=1; i<=$datalength; i++ )) ;do

x=`cat $data | awk '{print $1;}' | sed -n "$i"p | sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'` ; x=`echo "$x" | bc -l`       ; echo "x$i=$x";
y=`cat $data | awk '{print $2;}' | sed -n "$i"p | sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'` ; y=`echo "$y" | bc -l`       ; echo "y$i=$y";
z=`cat $data | awk '{print $3;}' | sed -n "$i"p | sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'` ; z=`echo "$z" | bc -l`       ; echo "z$i=$z";

# do something with xyz:

fslmaths ~/data/standard/MNI152_T1_2mm -mul 0 -add 1 -roi $x 1 $y 1 $z 1 0 1 point -odt float > NewFile$i

done
```

The `bc` and the `sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'` have to be added if you like to use floating point numbers and for the case that input also uses exponential notation.

I had a similar problem but for lots of input data those bash scripts are very slow. I migrated to perl then. In perl it would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open (IN, "data.dat") or die "Error opening";

my $i=0;
for my $line (<IN>){
$i++;
open(OUT, ">NewFile$i.out");
chomp $line;
(my $x,my $y,my $z) = split '\t',$line;
print "$x $y $z\n";

# do something with xyz:

my $f= fslmaths ~/data/standard/MNI152_T1_2mm -mul 0 -add 1 -roi $x 1 $y 1 $z 1 0 1 point -odt float

print OUT "f= $f\n";
close OUT;
}
close IN;
```

Comment: @Ed Morton Can you please explain why my solution has a ton of errors? I am here to learn and I am really interested in your opinion.